# JAVA - I need to change relative paths to absolut paths in JSOUP

Tags: java, path, html-parsing, jsoup, html-parser

I'm new in jsoup Java HTML Parser.

I have the following code:

```
String url =”http://bestSite.com”;
  try{
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
File input = new File("/somePath/output.html");
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(input, "UTF-8");
Elements element = document.getElementsByClass(“logo”);
  writer.write(element.outerHtml());
  writer.flush();
  writer.close();
}
```

In

> output.html

I receive relative path:

```
<img src="/images/fun.png"
```

instead of absolute path:

```
<img src=”http://bestSite.com/image/fun.png”
```

How do I change it?

> The answer is:

```
Elements media = document.select("img[src]");
for (Element src : media) {
src.attr("src", src.absUrl("src"));
}
```

Comment: That does not depend on you, the webpage is written that way. If you want to get the absolut path, you should parse it yourself, that is, add 'http://bestSite.com' before all `Img[src]` tags.

Comment: Do you want the whole tag or just the src path ?

Comment: Just the src path. I understand that should parse it myself by adding bestSite.com before all Img[src] tags, but how to do it?)

Comment: Ok so, see my answer bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSoup you can get the absolute instead of relative, but only when retrieving attributes :

```
String relativeSrc = elment.attr("src");
String absoluteSrc = elment.attr("abs:src");
```

So you can do :

```
for (Element element : elements) {
     String absoluteSrc = elment.attr("abs:src");       
}
```